# How to generate red colour automatically in each div tag of 3*3 block using setInterval Using JavaScript? how colour is counting?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This is my output and I want this red color is generated automatically by `setInterval`:

[image: This is my output and I want this red color is generated automatically by setInterval]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add some explanation on what you have tried and what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Welcome buddy! Great to hear that you started to learn web development. But, if you want us to assist and provide you precise help, you need to be more descriptive and maybe provide some examples. Good luck!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand your question, but I have done something anyways.

```js
const gridItem1 = document.querySelector('.grid-item-1');

setInterval(() => {
  gridItem1.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}, 2000)
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 80px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 80px);
}

.grid-item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-1"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-4"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-5"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-6"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-7"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-8"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-9"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript simply takes the first grid item (`grid-item-1`) and changes its `background-color` to red.

One thing that needs to be noticed is here the JavaScript is adding **`inline`** style, which is not always a good idea.

Other thing you can do is to have a class and then add the class after a set amount of time.

*Here's an example:*

```js
const gridItem1 = document.querySelector('.grid-item-1');

setInterval(() => {
  gridItem1.classList.add('red-div')
}, 2000)
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
}

.grid-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.red-div {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-1"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-4"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-5"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-6"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-7"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-8"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-9"></div>
</div>
```

**Thank You!**

Comment: i m really sorry.. for wrong question which I uploaded.. ,Actually my question is I want to generate red color which is generated randomly in each 9 blocks after 1sec.. when I hit the start button

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use timeout before the start of the function in am not sure but i have this

```js
let gridItem = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
const btn = document.querySelector('#start');
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
    let rand = getRandomInt(0,gridItem.length);
      gridItem[rand].classList.add('red')
      gridItem = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item:not(.red)');
  },1000)
})


function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 80px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 80px);
}

.grid-item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-1"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-4"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-5"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-6"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-7"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-8"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-9"></div>
</div>
<button id="start">start</button>
```

## interval use

```js
let gridItem = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
const btn = document.querySelector('#start');
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  let interval = setInterval(()=>{
    let rand = getRandomInt(0,gridItem.length);
      gridItem[rand].classList.add('red')
      gridItem = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item:not(.red)');
      if(!gridItem.length){
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
  },1000)
})


function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 80px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 80px);
}

.grid-item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-1"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-4"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-5"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-6"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-7"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-8"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-9"></div>
</div>
<button id="start">start</button>
```